# What is the benefit of pre validate unique name with fluent validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

In my aspnet core 3.1 application I am using MediatR pattern and fluent validation. I am checking uniqueness of project name. I can use to approach for validate. Both of them works fine.

**1st scenario**

Validate inside **IRequestHandler**

```
 if (await _context.Projects.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == request.Name.ToLower())
                    .AnyAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)) throw new BadRequestException($"{request.Name.ToLower()} already exists");
```

**2nd scenario**

Validate inside **AbstractValidator**

```
    public class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public CommandValidator(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotNull().NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify project 
                name").AlphaNumeric()
               .MustAsync(BeUniqueTitle).WithMessage("Project name already exists");
        }

        private async Task<bool> BeUniqueTitle(string title, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _context.Projects.AllAsync(l => l.Name != title.ToLower(), cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        }
        
    }
```

My question as both of them are checking db and performance as I tested in postman almost same (time for checking). Which approach should I follow? Which one is recommended to use.